# AngularJS code is not running and getting no error message when inspected

Tags: angularjs

When I inspect it, there are no error and it's returning nothing so, apparently not running :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
.message {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app='LunchChecker'>
    <div class="container" ng-controller='MyLunchCheckController'>
        <h1>Lunch Checker</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="lunch-menu" type="text" placeholder="list comma separated dishes 
                 you usually have for lunch" class="form-control" ng-model='MenuInput'>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="checkInput()">
                Check If Too Much</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group message" {{checkInput()}}>
            <!-- Your message can go here. -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Below is the `app.js` script for the above view  the purpose of the code is to return either `msg1` if the input is less than 3 menu or `msg2` if the input is more than 3 :

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('LunchChecker', [])
        .controller('MyLunchCheckController', MyLunchCheckController);

    MyLunchCheckController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function MyLunchCheckController($scope) {
        $scope.MenuInput = [].slice;
        $scope.values = new Array($scope.MenuInput.length);
        $scope.msg1 = "Enjoy!";
        $scope.msg2 = "Too much!";

        //fucntion for the button to check the user input menu-list

        $scope.checkInput = function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.values; i++) {

                if ($scope.values <= 3) {
                    return $scope.msg1;
                } else {
                    return $scope.msg2;
                }
            }
        };
    }

})();
```

Comment: How you are passing the current value from view to controller? Value which you are initializing is done before anything is written in the text box. If I am understanding this wrong can you create a plunker for this?

Comment: @ Vineet Agrawal  this exactly what i want the page to display: If the user typed "list comma separated dishes you usually have for lunch" in this place holder and their lunch list is less or equal to 3 i should get msg1 else msg2 so nothing has been passed when the page loads! When you said "Value which you are initializing is done before anything is written in the text box." i kind of getting confused! take me as beginner and help from that angle thanks.

Comment: https://rexie18.github.io/AngularJs-mod1-solution/

Answer (score 0):

When I try to reflect your code, I am getting `function slice() { [native code] }` inside the text box. As you have initialised the value of MenuInput as [].slice.

So to improve and compare the code

```
'use strict';

angular.module('LunchChecker', [])
  .controller('MyLunchCheckController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.msg1  =   "Enjoy!";
     $scope.msg2  =   "Too much!";

     $scope.checkInput  =  function() {
            if($scope.MenuInput.split(",").length <= 3) {
                $scope.values = $scope.msg1;
            } else{
                $scope.values = $scope.msg2;
            }
    };   
  }]);
```

It will print the message in the console according to the length you compare. For displaying the message you can write like:

```
<div class="form-group message" {{checkInput()}}>
```

to

```
<div class="form-group message"> {{values}}</div>
```

Comment: thansk alot this is what i did 

'use strict';
     
    angular.module('LunchChecker', [])
   .controller('MyLunchCheckController', MyLunchCheckController);
     
    MyLunchCheckController.$inject  =  ['$scope'];
    function MyLunchCheckController($scope) {
    $scope.MenuInput= [];
     $scope.msg1  =   "Enjoy!";
     $scope.msg2  =   "Too much!";

     $scope.checkInput  =  function() {
            if($scope.MenuInput.split(",").length <= 3) {
                $scope.values = $scope.msg1;
            } else{
                $scope.values = $scope.msg2;